# HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'userid' is not present

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i tried this code for login page and am getting the above error , am new to spring please help me.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")

public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginser;

    @RequestMapping("/loginadmin")
    public String loginAdmin() {

        return "loginadmin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginemployee")
    public String loginEmployee() {

        return "loginemployee";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/adminvalidate")
    public @ResponseBody String validateAdmin(@RequestParam(value="userid") String userid, @RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
        String result = loginser.validate(userid, password);
        if (result.equals("pass")) {
            return "redirect:/admin/view";
        }
        return "error";
    }

}
```

ui

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Admin Login</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">

        <form:form action="adminvalidate" 
            method="POST">

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>User-Id : </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" path="emp_Id" placeholder="User Id" id="userid"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Password : </label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" path="emp_firstname" placeholder="Password" id="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

                    <input type="button" value="back" onclick="window.location.href='/';return false">


        </form:form>

    </div>
</div>
```

i need to write code for login page that to check the credentials and am getting 400 error

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. You have the tools to paste it here, it'll be formatted for you. If someone tries to reproduce your error for debugging, they'll have to write the entire code themselves with a picture as a reference. It is unlikely anyone's gonna do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put an image instead of code ,I can not see the entire code of yours,

According to your question,the reason is the `userid` parameter is not passed to your controller method,check if you have set the name of user id input element as below:

```
<input type='text' name='userid' path='emp_id'>
```

Another possible way to avoid this issue is set the `required=false` in your controller method:

```
public @ResponseBOdy String validateAdmin(@RequestParam(value="userid",required=false)){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

400 error comes when the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax. check your URL syntax and you didn't give the method name in controller Like POST